# JSF: Controller that relies on another controller?

Tags: model-view-controller, jsf, controller, dependencies

I'm working on a project where we have a `FooViewController`, and a `BarListController`.  The list of `Bars` now needs to depend on the `Foo` being viewed.  So does anyone have a recommendation of how to do this?

I don't need an answer from an implementation perspective, necessarily, but more from a design perspective.  That is:

- Should the `FooViewController` somehow tell the `BarListController` what `Foo` is being viewed?
- Should the `BarListController` ask the `FooViewController` what `Foo` is being viewed?
- In either case, how do you inject these things into one another? (This part I need implementation help ;-) )

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, the bean where you're invoking the concrete action should ask for it as method argument or as managed property.

So, if you're using a Servlet 3.0 / EL 2.2 capable container, then pass `Foo` as method argument:

```
<h:commandLink value="Bar list"
    action="#{barListController.list(fooViewController.foo)}" />
```

with

```
public void list(Foo foo) {
    this.list = barService.list(foo);
}
```

If you're not on EL 2.2 yet, then set `Foo` as managed property:

```
<h:commandLink value="Bar list"
    action="#{barListController.list}" />
```

with

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class BarListController {

    @ManagedProperty("#{fooViewController.foo}")
    private Foo foo;

    public void list() {
        this.list = barService.list(foo);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I'm using Servlet 3.0 and this is perfect.  Thanks!